# Matching a nested column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 5 columns, and one of the columns is a list. If I print out the list only, I get something like this:

```
Row(a='abc',b='def',c=['qwe','rty'])
Row(a='123',b='456',c=['789','089'])
...
```

I'm trying to match on the field `a` and also on the list `c` (separately). For example, if I match for `a='abc'`, I would get the first Row (the entire dataframe with all 5 columns), and if I match for `089` in `c`, I will get the second Row (the entire dataframe with all 5 columns).

I wrote this function for matching against `a`, but the results only contain the `Row`, i.e. without the other 4 non-nested columns. I can't figure out how to refer back to the dataframe itself from the match. Is there a way where I can match and get the dataframes that match `a` or an element in `c`?

```
def find_a(nested_col_list, a_value):
    for nested_cols in nested_col_list:
        for nested_col in nested_cols:
            if nested_col.a == a_value:
                print(nest_col)

find_a(df["nested_col"], "abc")
```

Comment: To be clear you are hoping to retrieve the entire row right? And you want to match against `a` **or** you want to match against an element of `c` either way you want the entire row?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the whole row, including the 4 columns that are not nested. I want to match against `a` or an element of `c` separately, i.e. 2 different calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after careful consideration of you what you have written I believe I understand what you want.
So right now you are being given only the row of this nested column... And what you want is the entire row of the main dataframe at this particular nested column instance.
Therefore you have two options... Either **enumerate** over the nested_col_list that way you have an index and return that from the function. Here's an example of the function returning the index in the dataframe where this match happens (this returns the first row where a match if sound for example.

```
def find_a(nested_col_list, a_value):
    for idx,nested_cols in enumerate(nested_col_list):
        for nested_col_row in nested_cols: #renamed the variable to be more appropriate as to what it is referencing
            if nested_col_row.a == a_value:
                return idx # This will return the index in the dataframe of the first occurrence where a is found.
            #you can also search c for the value as well.

find_a(df["nested_col"], "abc")
```

OR if you need to access the dataframe from this same function (using print for instance) then you will have to pass the entire dataframe to the function... With that said. I'll write up an example of doing such:

```
def find_a(df, a_value):
    nested_col_list = df["nested_col"]
    for idx,nested_cols in enumerate(nested_col_list):
        for nested_col_row in nested_cols: #renamed the variable to be more appropriate as to what it is referencing
            if nested_col_row.a == a_value:
                print(df.loc[[idx]]) #This will print out the entire row as well as the nested column.
            #you can also search c for the value as well.

find_a(df, "abc")
```

Comment: Thanks! Your `enumerate` solution was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following (explode lists and then look for string) :

**Source dataframe**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'a': ['abc', '123'],
    'b': ['def', '456'],
    'c': [['qwe','rty'], ['789','089']],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Finding function**

```py
def find(dfrm, col, value):
    r = (dfrm.explode(column=col, ignore_index=False)
             .query(f'{col} == "{value}"')
           )
    # ...
    for index in r.index.unique():
        yield dfrm.loc[index]
```

**Results**

```
# Ex. match for a value in col 'a'
matches = list(find(df, 'a', 'abc'))
print(matches)
#### [a           abc
#### b           def
#### c    [qwe, rty]
#### Name: 0, dtype: object]

# Ex. match for a value in col 'c'
matches = list(find(df, 'c', '089'))
print(matches)
#### matches
#### [a           123
#### b           456
#### c    [789, 089]
#### Name: 1, dtype: object]
```

Comment: I thought about using `explode` too, but there are many fields in the nested columns, and there are many rows, so I thought that would just lead to too many exploded dataframes.

Comment: I apologize for no comenting my code but this is not the way it processes. Only `dfrm` is exploded inside the function in order to read all the indexes of rows which include the searched value. This can be done with parameter `ignore_index` set to `False`. In second part for each unique index it yields the rows you are looking for. On the other hand, `df` is never exploded.